# Numpy statistics, creating an array with certain statistics properties

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have some numpy array, I can measure its mean, median, standard deviation, and so on with numpy routines, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.statistics.html

For example, for array `arr`, I would run

```
import numpy as np
print np.mean(arr) # prints the mean
print np.median(arr) # prints the median
```

However, for my purposes, instead of measuring the statistical properties after an array is created, I would like to create an array with data of distinct statistical properties.

So, for example, I would like to create an array shaped `(1000,)` of mean `2.5`, variance `10`, data points i.i.d. such that they are Gaussian draws, etc.

How could one do this with numpy?

Comment: Do you want to draw a random sample from a distribution whose mean is 2.5, or do you require that the actual mean of the sample array is 2.5?  I.e. do you expect, for the realization `arr`, that `np.mean(arr)` is exactly 2.5?  Or is it OK for the values in `arr` to be drawn from a distribution with mean 2.5, but because `arr` is a finite sample, its mean isn't necessarily 2.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.random.randn(size)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) which gives you normal(0,1) samples of length size.  So multiply by the standard deviation and add the mean:

```
import numpy as np
m = 2.5
std = np.sqrt(10)
v = m + std*np.random.randn(1000) 

print np.mean(v)  # 2.43375955445
print np.var(v)  # 9.9049376296
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can do this with numpy library

```
>>import numpy as np
>>import math
>>mean = 2.5
>>deviation = math.sqrt(10)
>>s = np.random.normal(mean,deviation, 1000)
```

It will give you 1000 Data points array which has mean value 2.5 and variance value 10.
For more information you can check this link http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

Comment: Nitpick: `s` is a realization from a distribution with mean 2.5 and variance 10, but, in general, the mean of `s` will not be 2.5 and the variance will not be 10.